# How to replace domain name for all "a" tag using cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to figure out how to replace the domain name for all "a" tags using cheerio but `$(this).attr("href")` returns undefined

```
function changeDomain(html) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  $("a").each((_, node) => {
    console.log($(this).attr("href")); // undefined
  });
  return $.html();
}
```

I want to change

from this

```
 <a href="HTTP://google.com/home">Home</a>
```

to this

```
 <a href="HTTP://example.com/home">Home</a>
```

Comment: Make sure `changeDomain` is being run once the document is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let a of $('a').get()){
  $(a).attr('href', $(a).attr('href').replace(/old/, 'new'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), they don't get `this`

use `$(node)` instead